# Using shell script to insert data into remote MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, bash, scripting, shell

I've been trying to get a shell(bash) script to insert a row into a REMOTE database, but I've been having some trouble :(

The script is meant to upload a file to a server, get a URL, HASH, and a file size, connect to a remote mysql database, and insert the data into an existing table. I've gotten it working until the remote MYSQL database bit.

It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

zxw=randomtext
description=randomtext2

for file in "$@"
 do
 echo -n *****
 ident= *****
 data= ****
 size=` ****
 hash=`****
mysql --host=randomhost --user=randomuser --password=randompass randomdb
insert into table (field1,field2,field3) values('http://www.example.com/$hash','$file','$size');
echo "done"
done
```

I'm a total noob at programming so yeah :P

Anyway, I added the \ to escape the brackets as I was getting errors. As it is right now, the script is works fine until connects to the mysql database. It just connects to the mysql database and doesn't do the insert command (and I don't even know if the insert command would work in bash).

PS: I've tried both the mysql commands from the command line one by one, and they worked, though I defined the hash/file/size and didn't have the escaping "".

Anyway, what do you guys think? Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so how?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The insert statement has to be sent to mysql, not another line in the shell script, so you need to make it a "here document".

```
mysql --host=randomhost --user=randomuser --password=randompass randomdb << EOF
insert into table (field1,field2,field3) values('http://www.site.com/$hash','$file','$size');
EOF
```

The `<< EOF` means take everything before the next line that contains nothing but `EOF` (no whitespace at the beginning) as standard input to the program.

Comment: Getting this error with that: line 22: warning: here-document at line 19 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')                             line 23: line 23: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @lelouch - you left off the "EOF" in the third line above.  It's kind of important to implement all of the solution, not just the first half.

Comment: Hmm nah, i clearly added the << EOF in the mysql line, and another EOF in a new line after the insert one. Any idea on whats wrong?

Comment: Saved by abit of googling: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1077291&tstart=0  Its working now!! You sir, are a genius, thank you ALOT! :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I probably should have mentioned that the EOF has to be at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Why are you trying to escape parentheses? Shell won't touch them and I doubt mysql needs those backslashes either.

Comment: I removed them to get the command to work. And I added them before as I was getting errors otherwise. Original post fixed accordingly for other ppl looking for the same solution

Comment: I copied from the original question.  Since they're not in the question any more, I've removed them from the answer.

Answer (score 11):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for but it is an option.

If you want to bypass the annoyance of actually including your query in the sh script, you can save the query as `.sql` file (useful sometimes when the query is REALLY big and complicated).  This can be done with simple file IO in whatever language you are using.

Then you can simply include in your sh scrip something like:

```
mysql -u youruser -p yourpass -h remoteHost < query.sql &
```

This is called batch mode execution.  Optionally, you can include the ampersand at the end to ensure that that line of the sh script does not block.

Also if you are concerned about the same data getting entered multiple times and your rdbms getting inconsistent, you should explore MySql transactions (commit, rollback, etc).

Answer (score 5):

Don't use raw SQL from bash; bash has no sane facility for sanitizing the data beforehand. Generate a CSV file and upload that instead.

Comment: It's meant to be completely automated with many files going through this process. If i use a CSV file or something, won't that lead to a possibility of duplicate entries of the same data? --> excuse my possible ignorance!

Comment: If you need a field or a certain set of fields to be unique throughout the table, then you should create a unique index.

Comment: I'd like to add that another answer on stack said to not use a csv file. If you're connected to a remote MySQL database then it's hard to generate the csv locally. You have to figure out some way to generate the csv remotely and then transfer it over to the local directory. The other answer recommended piping. So which is it? Do we use csvs or do we not?!