# bash scripting variable allocation when using here-document

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, eof

I am new to bash /mysql however I have found tons of help reading threw examples and other people's problems ...but have ran into one of my own . 
I am attempting to insert a row into an MySQL database table every time a file is added to a specific directory (for this i am using inotifywait ) anyways here is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
        filename= "false"
        filename= inotifywait --format "%f" -e create /var/www/media2net/torrent
        date_field= date +"%F":"%T"
        mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=admin Media2net << EOF
        insert into video (title, description, url_video, upload_date)
                values('testing','default_description','$filename', '$date_feild');
        EOF
        echo $filename
done
```

From this I have verified with echo the variable `$filename` is properly held at end of bash script however when i look at entry in the table the column url_video has it's default value and not the string represented by `$filename`

From what i can conclude the variable `$filename`  does not get passed through EOF 
i have tried as indicate here http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_access_mysql_with_bash_shell_script.htm

as well as this

[Using shell script to insert data into remote MYSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900496/using-shell-script-to-insert-data-into-remote-mysql-database)

any help of where i can find how to pass variable into query would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can't have spaces around the `=`. This command `filename= "false"` temporarily sets the environment variable "filename" to the empty string and then executes the program named "false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `filename` is set to the empty string (mind the spaces after the `=` sign!). You need

```
filename=$(inotifywait --format "%f" -e create /var/www/media2net/torrent)
```

Similarly,

```
date_field=$(date +"%F:%T")
```

and be careful, you have a typo in your `mysql` command (`date_field` and note `date_feild`):

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=admin Media2net <<EOF
insert into video (title, description, url_video, upload_date)
values('testing','default_description','$filename', '$date_field');
EOF
```

Now I hope that you're controlling the filenames. Imagine a filename that contains a single quote e.g., `hello'howdy`. You'll have a problem in your query. Worse, an evil user who puts a file named `whatever','something'); evil_mysql_command; whatever`, you'll have the evil command performed! One possibility is to sanitize the filename using `printf` thus:

```
printf -v filename '%q' "$(inotifywait --format "%f" -e create /var/www/media2net/torrent)"
```

This will at least escape the single quotes that could appear in a filename. See Gordon Davisson's comment: the `printf` trick will not prevent from all the possible attacks, so I really hope you absolutely control the name of the files!

All these suggestions yield the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    printf -v filename '%q' "$(inotifywait --format "%f" -e create /var/www/media2net/torrent)"
    date_field=$(date +"%F:%T")
    mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=admin Media2net <<EOF
    insert into video (title, description, url_video, upload_date) 
    values('testing','default_description','$filename', '$date_field');
    EOF
    echo "$filename"
done
```

## Edit.

To answer your question in the comment:

> why did the script properly echo `$filename` to my terminal but not send it properly to MySQL, does that have to do with string starting with a space? or something else completely?

That's because when you do something like:

```
whatever= command
```

then the variable `whatever` is set to the empty string, and the command `command` is executed (with the `whatever` variable set as environment variable). E.g.,

```
$ IFS='c' read a b c <<< "AcBcC"
$ echo "$a $b $c"
A B C
$ echo $IFS

$
```

In your script, the variable filename was in fact never globally set. You can check it by doing this:

```
$ filename= "false"
$ echo "$filename"

$
```

What happens is that the environment variable `filename` is set to empty string then the command `false` (which happens to exist) is launched using that environment variable and we're done.

When you do this:

```
filename= inotifywait --format "%f" -e create /var/www/media2net/torrent
```

the variable `filename` is set to the empty string, and then the command `inotifywait ...` is executed with `filename` as an environment variable (but `inotifywait` doesn't really care about it). *And that's what you saw on your terminal!* it was the output of this command. Then you probably saw an empty line, that was the output of

```
echo $filename
```

which was equivalent to

```
echo
```

since the variable `filename` expanded to an empty string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ahhh , thank you very much! your suggestion for filename worked!!! to satisfy my own curiosity why did the script properly echo $filename to my terminal but not send it properly to MySQL , does that have to do with string starting with a space? or something else completely?

Comment: i had not gotten that far yet no! though i was aware of something of the nature being a problem do you know of any references on the web that detail more problems of that nature?

Comment: Good point about SQL injection via the filename, but note that `printf ... '%q'` is not really sufficient if this type of attack is a possible problem. It does bash-style string quoting/escaping, while mysql has somewhat different quoting rules, and an attacker could take advantage of the difference. Defending properly against SQL injection is *hard*.

Comment: also this printf -v  line , returns an illegal option in ubuntu 12.04 though documentation suggest syntax is correct? anyways i will read up on preventing SQL injection as Gordon has made clear there is multiple steps involved

Comment: @brendanmorrison Make sure you're running `bash` and not `sh`. The `-v` option only works with the `printf` bash builtin.

Comment: thank you again you have been an array of information for me this morning, also  bash does indeed execute the script properly, i never new there was a difference between the 2 commands